# Android widget "Widget settings" shortcut on long press

Tags: android, android-widget, android-contextmenu, android-appshortcut

I want my widget to have a "configure widget" option along the default "app info" and "remove from home" I   get when creating a widget.
Ive being looking into the android documentations for a few hours and I cant find if there's a standard way of doing this.
I'm not sure if there's a standard android approach of adding menu items to this context menu or if its only something specific to the installed launcher but on my Samsung device, the pre-installed clock widget has this exact feature as shown here:
[image]

I tried adding an [app shortcut](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts) (but it is obviously not the case since a widget does not have a "LAUNCHER" activity)

I tried adding an [option menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#options-menu)

I tried adding different actions to my configuration activity.

any guidance or direction to the correct documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: "but on my Samsung device, the pre-installed clock widget has this exact feature" -- what is your launcher? If the answer is "Samsung's", then there is no requirement that this be an app widget. Do not draw conclusions about behavior based on a manufacturer's launcher. Always use a third-party launcher. Please bear in mind that there are hundreds of launchers, and none have to offer a context menu like this. There might be an `<intent-filter>` that you can use that some launchers will honor.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for your service to the community all those years, its an honor.  yes its the samsung launcher.  so if there is no standard widget context menu on most of the launchers whats my best approach if I don't want a visible button on my view? is the standard way is only having an app (launcher activity) to go along with the widget / accepting the user must remove and reset the widget to re-configure?

Comment: "so if there is no standard widget context menu on most of the launchers" -- I didn't say there wasn't one on most. I did say that there is no requirement that any have one. "is the standard way is only having an app (launcher activity) to go along with the widget" -- either that, or respond to click events in general and use them to launch a configuration activity. Most of the app widgets that I use treat clicks on non-button areas to be requests to launch some activity tied to the app widget (whether configuration or something else).

Comment: But, for example, I use Nova Launcher, and while it has a context menu, there is no "Settings" option for any app widget that I tried. I cannot rule out the possibility of some `<intent-filter>` convention that you could follow that some launchers might use, but you cannot assume that every launcher always offers support for it. Finally, thanks for the kind words!

Comment: @CommonsWare It works even on Microsoft and default Android launcher. The solution is a simple `android:widgetFeatures="reconfigurable"` as in the answer. It requires Android SDK 28.

Comment: @lionscribe: There is no "default Android launcher". I did miss this new app widget XML attribute, so thanks for that! Do note that the documentation states that these are hints; do not assume that any given launcher will pay attention to this flag or will do what you expect with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. 
it is specifically to add a "widget settings" feature to the context menu.

under your [provider info xml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo), simply add:

```
android:widgetFeatures="reconfigurable"
```

Comment: It works (on Android 28 and up). Please mark your answer as "Accepted".